# catch the first occurrence value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below `XML`.

```
<chapter num="1">
<section level="sect2">
<page>22</page>
</section>
<section level="sect3">
<page>23</page>
</section>
</chapter>
```

here I'm trying to get the first occurrence of `<page>`.

I'm using the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="ThisDocument" select="document('')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html>]]></xsl:text>

        <html>

            <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <section class="tr_chapter">
       <xsl:value-of select="//page[1]/text()"/>
            <div class="chapter">

            </div>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the output that I get all the `page` valyes printed. I only want the first one.

Current output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <section class="tr_chapter">2223
        <div class="chapter">
        </div>
      </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

the `page` values are printed here after `<section class="tr_chapter">`, i want only **22** but I'm getting **2223**
here I'm using `//page[1]/text()`, because I'm not sure that the `page` comes within the `section`, it is random.

please let me know how I can get only the first `page` value.

here is the transformation http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsR

Comment: just use `page[1]/text()`

Comment: it is not printing anything @JoelM.Lamsen, i've updated my question with the transformation link.

Comment: oops, should have been `descendant::page[1]/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//page)[1]"/>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsR/1

Note that this gets the value of the first page element in the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search the contents of the `chapter` context element in your template for the first `page` descendant then use `<xsl:value-of select="descendant::page[1]"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="(.//page)[1]"/>`.